# Narrow space between italic f and T with fourier font

Tags: fonts, spacing, fourier

consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[%
11pt,
]{scrbook}


\usepackage[widespace]{fourier}
\begin{document}
of Theorem
\emph{
of Theorem. 
}
\end{document}
```

The space between f and T is very narrow with fourier font even when passing the widespace option (seems not to have any effect, though).

Is there a way to fix this without changing the font?

EDIT:
I realised, that the problem came up in a situation, where there is less whitespace for all words, see the following example

```
\documentclass[%
paper=17cm:24cm,
DIV=12,
11pt,
]{scrbook}


\usepackage{fourier}
\begin{document}
\emph{
    \quad\qquad\qquad of Theorem\\
assumptions of Theorem 2.6 hold. Further, let $c\in\mathbb R$  be given such that $1 < c < \lambda/\sigma$. Choose
}
\end{document}
```

See the second example in:

[image]

Comment: For my opinion the space seem be good.

Comment: If you get rid of the extra horizontal space because of the new line after the \emph{ it actually looks fine to my eyes The space between the f and T looks the same within the italics as the upright but the other extra space makes it look tighter. Just add a `%` after the `\emph{`; i.e., `\emph{%`.

Comment: hmm, I guess I don't like the space between the top of f and T with italics

Answer (score 5):

There is a difference with the widespace option:

[image]

But you can enlarge the space like this, but it will change all word space, also between other letters.

```
\documentclass[%
11pt,
]{scrbook}


\DeclareRobustCommand{\SetFourierSpace}{%
\fontdimen2\font=1.6\fontdimen2\font} %adapt the 1.6 default with widespace is 1.23
\usepackage{fourier}

\begin{document}
of Theorem 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice..and I approve your answer.

Comment: I approve too. :-)

Comment: @Mico Do you copy me?   no aahahah.